# Can not modify global variable in an asynchronous function (coroutine) in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, coroutine

I run this code in jupyter notebook(python 3.6.8). I expect the code to print 2 as the result, somehow it still prints 1. I want to know why.

```py
import asyncio
x = 1

async def func():
    global x
    x = 2
    print(x)

await func()
print(x)
```

And the result is:
[image]

The jupyter notebook environment I am using is:

- jupyter core     : 4.6.3
- jupyter-notebook : 6.1.4
- qtconsole        : 4.7.7
- ipython          : 7.16.1
- ipykernel        : 5.3.4
- jupyter client   : 6.1.7
- jupyter lab      : 2.2.9
- nbconvert        : 6.0.7
- ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
- nbformat         : 5.1.2
- traitlets        : 4.3.3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a global variable in `IPython` coroutine you have to acquire the `asyncio.Lock`.

```
import asyncio

x = 1

async def func():
    global x
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    await lock.acquire()
    x = 2
    lock.release()

await func()
print(x)  # 2
```

Comment: In fact, Jupyter Notebook use a asynchronous REPL: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/autoawait.html

Comment: the asynchronous REPL already has an event loop, and can run coroutine directly by adding await in front of a coroutine. Your code gives me this error when I run it in my jupyter notebook:
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Comment: this Runtime Error happends when it runs this line: `loop.run_until_complete(func())`

Comment: Then instead of `asyncio.get_event_loop` try with `asyncio.get_running_loop`. This will give you the already running loop in which you can run the coroutine.

Comment: it gives this error: `AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'get_running_loop'`

Comment: I editted the original question. As you can see the coroutine really runs as the `print(x)` in the aasync func is excuted ( it printed out 2).