# how to remove value from list safely in asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

There is a global `list` to store data. Different async functions maybe `add` or `remove` value from it.

Example:

```
a = [] # List[Connection]

async def foo():
    for v in a:
        await v.send('msg')
       

async def bar():
    await SomeAsyncFunc()
    a.pop(0)
```

Both `foo` and `bar` will give up the control to let other coroutines run, so in `foo`, it is not safe to remove value from the list.

Comment: This looks like a dangerous anti-pattern. Apart from that, you should not remove items from a list that you are looping through. Why don't you change the list first and then call the async function? If the other async function needs some information from a, then provide it as argument. In any case, "Explicit is better than implicit." (The Zen of Python), so try to avoid globals if possible.

Comment: That kind of issue can occur if you're using Jupyter Notebook, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72586884/can-not-modify-global-variable-in-an-asynchronous-function-coroutine-in-python/72587569#72587569).

Comment: @CarlosHorn I change the example code.I have to  use a global var to store the all connection like websocket

Comment: In this case, use a lock as suggested by the answer posted by @ArtyomVancyan. In case you want to be very clean, you may want to write a connections container class which internally does the locking business.

Comment: @CarlosHorn Yes, use a lock is a solution. Is there a more elegant way to do this

Comment: The more elegant way is to use the lock with a context manager like: `async with asyncio.Lock()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows how to use the lock for this:

Create a connection manager:

```
import asyncio

class ConnectionsManager:
    def __init__(self, timeout=5):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self._lock = asyncio.Lock()
        self._connections = []
    
    async def __aenter__(self):
        await asyncio.wait_for(self._lock.acquire(), timeout=self.timeout)
        return self._connections

    async def __aexit__(self, *exc):
        self._lock.release()
```

The timeout is a security measure to break bugs with circular waits.

The manager can be used as follows:

```
async def foo():
    for _ in range(10):
        async with cm as connections:
            # do stuff with connection
            await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
            connections.append('foo')
        
async def bar():
    for _ in range(5):
        async with cm as connections:
            # do stuff with connection
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
            if len(connections) > 1:
                connections.pop()
            else:
                connections.append('bar')

cm = ConnectionsManager()
t1 = asyncio.create_task(foo())
t2 = asyncio.create_task(bar())
await t1
await t2
async with cm as connections:
    print(connections)
```

Note, that you could also be more explicit with connections here:

```
async def foo(cm):
    ...
async def bar(cm):
    ...
```

Just to make a comment why being explicit is so beneficial in contrast to globals. At some point you may need to write unit tests for your code, where you will need to specify all inputs to your functions/methods. Forgetting conditions on implicit inputs to your function (used globals) can easily result in untested states. For example your `bar` coroutine expects an element in the list `a` and will break if it is empty. Most of the time it might do the right thing, but one day in production...